# Can I go on holiday to Spain if I got a 6-month leave to enter stamp in my passport?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, eu-citizens, leave-to-enter

I'm visiting my partner and my daughter since September 2023. My partner is settled and daughter is British. She has depression and I came from the Czech republic to the UK to visit them and be there for both of them. I'm not living here or claiming benefits etc.

I booked a flight on 28 February. I recieved in Stansted airport a 6-month leave to enter stamp. I bought a holiday to Spain for 6 days starting 1st of February.

Someone told me I need to apply for EU scheme, so I was listening to the wrong people. My aplication was refused because I was thinking I must apply for it but I found out at the end that I don't really need this if I don't want to live here.

So my question is, can I go on holiday with my partner and will they let me enter again the UK? I got a flight ticket booked anyway to fly back to the Czech republic.

Thank you.

Comment: A **leave to enter** expires when you leave the UK. When you return to the UK a new leave to enter will be issued depending on the circumstances. Nobody can say for sure what the immigration official will decide. Since you have only stayed around 1 month of 6 and have a return ticket 3 weeks after your second arrival, a second leave to enter will probably be granted (possibly less than 6 months).

Comment: i stayed in uk to hold my partner due to her mental break down so i can helo her with our daughter from last september i didnt work or anything .

Comment: You should definitely take your return ticket with you. The danger here is that the immigration official may fear that you may be staying longer than allowed. Here possibly a leave to enter for 1 month may be issued.

Comment: what  should i say to the border officer in case please ? should i take my daughter birth certificate ir any documentation ?

Comment: The risk is indeed that when you return, the border officer will think you were trying to do a "visa run" to Spain to get a new 6-months leave to enter, and that you are effectively trying to "live in the UK through repeated or successive visits", especially as you will have stayed for 5 months of the last 6, and that you have ties in the UK (partner and daughter). Your return ticket is a good thing, but any evidence that you have to return to the Czechia would be even better. It's indeed likely that they will give you a shorter leave to enter.